# Error page does not work in production for Sapper export

Tags: javascript, static-files, sapper

Basically not existing routes get catched when using the `dev` command and the error / 404 page gets displayed. But when using `export` and uploading the generated files to a webserver this does not work. Instead, the index page is displayed, but none of the logic works, like clicking on another link for navigation.

I had a catch all slug before in the code, but removed and deleted all the files that were generated by the `export` command, to make sure that it is removed. Could this be the issue? How would the slugs file look like?

Comment: You should use a proper exporting tool instead of `sapper export`.

Comment: @pishpish `sapper export` is the proper and recommended tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `sapper export` the script will start from your index page and visit (and render) all pages reachable by links on the page. This way you have a *static* version of your website that you upload to your hosting. It replaces the server side rendering sapper normally does, but just for the first page the user visits, all the rest will start work as normal.

Since a 404 page is shown when the user goes somewhere that does not exist you will (usually) not have a link there and therefore the script will not render that page.

In order to tell sapper to also crawl that page you have to add it as an entry point

In `package.json`

```
"export": "sapper export --entry "/ /404""
```

This extra paramater will tell the script to start at */* (the main index file) and do the entire process again, starting at */404* (which shouldn't exist and thus throw your error page)

Comment: This looks good. Two quick questions: There are only three " in your example, shouldn't there be more? Would this be syntactically correct: `"export": "sapper export --entry \"/ /404\""` My export used the `--legacy` parameter. Is this still needed?

Comment: Yes, I am indeed missing a ", you can still use legacy parameter, I stripped the command from everything that was irrelevant for clarity's sake

Comment: Do I have to create a page 404.svelte? Does it not crawl the _error.svelte?

Comment: no, as soon as it does not find the page it will rendr `_error.svelte` , but it is best to set 404 as your entry post as this will result in a `404` file in the export and most hosting services will expect you to provide a file like that

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work on the server. Still the *dead* index page gets rendered. What is strange is that it works when I do the export locally and use the `npx` command to serve the build locally. We use an aws bucket for this in production. Could that be a problem?

Comment: I think sapper exports a _folder_ 404 (check the output folder), so you would need to setup some redirect on your server, unfamiliar with aws buckets unfortunately